How to securely pass personal information to a Bedrock agent?
I'm working with an AWS Bedrock agent and need to pass personal user information to it so it can provide personalized responses. However, I don't want to include this personal information directly in the agent's knowledge base for security reasons. Here are the details of my situation:
Environment:
I'm using AWS Bedrock for conversational AI.
The knowledge base contains general, non-sensitive information.
Personal user information needs to be used along with the knowledge base to provide personalized responses.
Requirements:
Personal information should not be permanently stored in the agent's knowledge base for security and privacy reasons.
The solution must respect user privacy and comply with data protection regulations.
What is the best way to temporarily pass personal information to the Bedrock agent, so it is only used for the current session and not stored?
If it is necessary to include personal information in the knowledge base, how can I do it securely without compromising user privacy?
In summary, I would like to know how to pass this personal information to the agent so that we can, along with the general information, provide personalized responses to the user. The user will be logged into the application, so we have their ID to access their information.

When invoking the bedrock agent, you can make use of sessionState -> promptSessionAttributes.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/agents-session-state.html
